# Objective-C and inheritance: forbidding Foundation subclasses from using superclass methods

Tags: objective-c, class, inheritance, subclass, overriding

Let's say I'm subclassing `NSString`, for example. My subclass is named `MyString`, and I want to override `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, but also add another parameter, so my method would be `[MyString stringWithParameter:format:]`. This method would serve to replace `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`.

If this was my setup, users would still be able to call `[MyString stringWithFormat:]`, which would in turn call `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`. Is there a way to stop users from calling `[MyString stringWithFormat:]`? In other words, is there a way to prevent a subclass of an object from calling particular methods of its parent class?

Comment: If you're subclassing `NSString`, you're probably doing something the hard way.

Comment: That may be. This is more of a hypothetical than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use compiler attributes to mark the method unavailable. In your header file:

```
 + (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ... __attribute__((unavailable("Do not call +stringWithFormat")));
```

This will cause a compiler error and prevent the method from being used.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/31h1AF4.png]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As others have hinted at, `NSString` is a class cluster, and as such can be quite tricky to subclass correctly. But apparently your question was about broader concepts of subclassing, rather than about dealing with the added complexity of class clusters, so let's leave that aside.

Rather than thinking in terms of preventing callers from sending `stringWithFormat:` to an instance of `MyString`, consider having your `MyString` class override `stringWithFormat:` to call your custom `stringWithParameter:format:` method and provide a default value for the `parameter` argument.

As @Stephen Melvin pointed out, typically your custom method would then call `[super stringWithFormat:]` to preserve the existing functionality.

**EDIT**

Here are a few points to consider when subclassing a class cluster:

> A new class that you create within a class cluster must:
>
> - Be a subclass of the cluster’s abstract superclass
> - Declare its own storage
> - Override all initializer methods of the superclass
> - Override the superclass’s primitive methods (described below)

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html

If you feel like it'd be worth the effort, Mike Ash has a great blog post on how to go about it: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-03-12-subclassing-class-clusters.html

But the first question to ask yourself is: "What problem am I trying to solve by subclassing `NSString` (or whatever the case may be), and is there perhaps a simpler approach to solving the problem?"

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on the complications of subclassing a class cluster?